# load Local PDF file in Application without shareintent or any onther pdfreader application

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I want to load local PDF file in our application in horizontal scrollview or viewpager is this possible or not?

if yes then suggest me any library or code...

thank is Advance...

Comment: are you able to load PDF? Share code please.

Comment: Gauraw i haven't any code i am ask to all of you is this possible or not if possible then give me code or suggestion....

Answer (score 1):

Use [Android PDFView](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview) library.

**Include PDFView in your layout:**

```
<com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**Load a PDF file:**

```
pdfView.fromAsset(pdfName)
    .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3)
    .defaultPage(1)
    .showMinimap(false)
    .enableSwipe(true)
    .onDraw(onDrawListener)
    .onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener)
    .onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
    .load();
```

Comment: because m try to impliment but demos show error in library and error is package name if you have demo then give me link....

Comment: Sample that I did some time ago: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5QJ6Sc0HcwWeGpUdUxIRXRaRjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: but still not working in my eclipse i am try to solve this project issue but i can't fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74555/discussion-between-rv-panchal-and-fida1989).

Answer (score 1):

As of API level 21, you can use [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) and an example [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/PdfRendererBasic/index.html)

If you are trying to target API's below 21 (you should), then I am afraid you will need external libs to do the job and hope that someone makes a port of PdfRenderer soon.